# Capture Output of Alt-SysRq Command Input via "True" Linux Console

Tags: linux, console

Couldn't find an answer to this basic question, prolly due to weak Google-fu...

Open a "true" console in Linux (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>)

Login to the newly opened console as user

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>SysRq</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> ([Thanks!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/211208/144299))

You will see a menu of options appear on the console screen.

**Question: How do I output said menu of options to a text file?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of all Alt-SysRq commands is initially sent *not* to console screen directly but to the **kernel message log**, which is then written to the console (subject to the "console logging level").

The contents of the kernel log are available through `dmesg`, and in most cases also copied to regular system logs (e.g. `journalctl -k` or `/var/log/messages`). Use regular shell redirection with these tools to store the results in a text file:

```
dmesg | tail > log.txt
```

Alternatively, the contents of the console screen can be read from /dev/vcs1 – you will need to use something like `fold` to wrap the contents into X×Y lines:

```
width=$(sudo stty -F /dev/tty1 size | awk '{print $2}')

sudo fold -w $width /dev/vcs1
```

Use [peekvc](https://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/peekvc/) if you want to grab colors and other attributes as well.

```
sudo peekvc 1
```

Comment: This works even when said keyboard command is entered into a GUI terminal emulator (although the output will not be visible in said terminal emulator's window) - excellent! Also, a comment by a user (which has since been deleted) mentioned that said output could be viewed by `sudo cat /dev/vcs1`. This is also a good answer and will be upvoted if the original commenter wishes to enter an answer...